# IE : get object from event

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

I want to get href attribute when a use clicks on a URL.

I've tried with:

```
var e = clickedElement || window.event;
var t = e.target || e.srcElement;
alert(t.href);
```

This is working fine in Chrome and Firefox, but there's a problem with IE; its give an error null.

What is possible solution to get href from event object?

Comment: Show us the function which contains this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what `clickedElement` is, given that its either the event object argument placeholder or a `this` argument;

```
function event_obj(event) {
    if (!event) var event = window.event;
    var element = event.target || event.srcElement;
    alert(element.href);
    return false;
}
function element_obj(element) {
    alert(element.href)
    return false;
}
.
.
<a href=".." onclick="return event_obj();">foo</a>
<a href=".." onclick="return element_obj(this);">bar</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to get the event target

```
function getEventTarget(event) {
    var targetElement = null;
    try {
        if (typeof event.target != "undefined") {
            targetElement = event.target;
        }
        else {
           targetElement = event.srcElement;
        }            
   } catch (ex) { alert("getEventTarget failed: " + ex); }
          return targetElement;
   };
```

Then call it when you trigger the event

```
   function evtrigger(ev) {
       alert(getEventTarget(ev).href);
   }
```

Note the getEventTarget() function works for all events so the DOM object returned can be manipulated any way you like, not just to get the href.